# Node power off, but still showing daemonset pod running

Tags: kubernetes

One worker node was powered off, get node status by `kubectl get nodes` shows that node is `NotReady`.

But `kubectl get po -o wide --all-namespaces|egrep 'daemonSet-pod|node-hostname'`, it shows some `DaemonSet` pods still running on `NotReady` node and cannot connect to these pods.

Why `Daemonset` pod still show `Running` even if the node `NotReady`?

Answer (score 1):

After kubernetes version 1.13, Tolerations like  `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready` are added automatically to `DaemonSets`. That means `DaemonSet` pods will not be evicted when there are node problems like you describe.